# Changing div element depending on current page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm a php guy trying to work with C# for the first time. I have a master page with the following navigation code I'd like to dynamically change depending on the webpage:

main.master:

```
...
<ul class="nav-menu">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">link A</li>
   <li><a href="#">link B</li> 
   <li><a href="#">link C</li>
</ul>
...
```

As of now, the class="active" is hard coded, but I'd like to put some conditions such as:

```
<li //Condition: if (page=="link") print "class=\"active\""; //><a href="#">whatever link it's supposed to be</li>
```

I can do this in PHP, but I'm just not sure how to do it the C#'s ASP.net way.

I have the following structure:

```
    - main.master --
    -- pageA.aspx
    -- pageB.aspx
    -- pagec.aspx
```

such that the current page is loaded via:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and looks like:

```
    x x x x x x x x x x x x x
    x main.master x x x x x x
    x Nav A x Nav B x Nav C x
    x x x 
    x x x   p p p p p p p p p 
    x x x   p Crnt page x p p
    x x x   p p p p p p p p p
```

I'd like to have the class ".active" applied to the main.master dynamically depending on whatever page variable is set by the current page.

**tldr:** I guess, what I'm also looking for is a simple way of doing the following: `<?php //some code here ?>`

edit:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//check for conditions of home
...
        this.isActiveHome.Text = @"<li class=""active""><a href=""Default.aspx"">Home</a></li>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<?php ?>` equivalent is `<%= %>`

If you're doing a lot of logic, it's best practice to do that logic in the code behind (.aspx.cs) and render the controls there.

A better option is the BulletedList:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx

Build the `BulletedList` control by adding the `Items` in the `Page_Load` method.

You can get the page name using:

```
string pageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! I have a slight confusion over the @" "; and <%= %> when do I use which?

Comment: @"" is used fore verbatim strings, meaning what is inside the quotes is not escaped. They are completely different, and @"" is not for ASPX markup, it's a .NET feature. You might want to get a book on C# and ASP.NET WebForms to get yourself started. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the help and clarification. I was able to create a aspx.cs code to customize the navigation.